# Mandrill: Conditional merge tags not working when rendering template

Tags: node.js, templates, express, render, mandrill

I've tried conditional merge tags(i.e something like *|IF:MY_NUM!=0|*), it works as expected when sending emails. But when I try to render a template, given the same global_merge_vars and merge_vars, all the content within the IF merge tag block just remains blank. I got the rendered html code and render it with ExpressJS. Did I lose something?